# fuse: How do I get the size of the file that is going to be written before it's written?

Tags: c, fuse

When a file is written, the `write` function corresponding with `.write` in `fuse_operations` is called for each file segment.

This means that for a larger file (e.g. 12720 bytes), the write function could be called 4 times with

```
1. size=4096, offset=0
2. size=4096, offset=4096
3. size=4096, offset=8192
4. size=432, offset=12288
```

because it has 4 segments with max segment size of 4096 bytes.

Inside the `write` function, I'd like to determine when the last segment size is being `write`n. I'm intending to put all the segments into a buffer, and use this last written segment to signal that the buffer now contains the entire object, so that it can be put somewhere else (such as an object store). By knowing the size of the object being written before it's written, I can just do a simple equality test `file_size == size + offset` to determine when the last segment is being written.

Comment: You need an explicit end of file indicator. In C it's `fclose()`. In your case it could be either a special function like that or an additional parameter to your I/O functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I can't. I can only put the entire object somewhere else (such as an object store) after the file handler is closed.

Answer (score -1):

If the length of your chunk is less than 4096, you know that you're at the end of the file.  Go ahead and write out the contents of your buffer!

Comment: Nice, and what if my file is 4*4096 ?